# Swift var type for class

Tags: swift

I have the next example where I have a problem to initialize the variable `tmpClass`, I tried `Any`, `AnyObject`, `AnyClass` ... but without success. I need to change and call the class dynamically from one variable

```
class One{
  func doSomething()->Int{ return 100 } 
}

class Two{
  func doSomething()->Int{ return 200 }
}

class begin{

   var tmpClass = ???
   var type = "One"

   switch (type){

      case "One":
      tmpClass = One()

      case "Two":
      tmpClass = Two()
   }

   println(tmpClass.doSomething())

}
```

the question is what type need to be `tmpClass` or some method to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways, see which fits you better:

## Protocols

### Create a protocol for `doSomething`

```
protocol DoSomethingProtocol {
    func doSomething()->Int
}
```

### Make your classes conform to it

```
class One : DoSomethingProtocol {
    func doSomething()->Int{ return 100 }
}

class Two : DoSomethingProtocol{
    func doSomething()->Int{ return 200 }
}
```

### Set your `tempClass` variable to be of a protocol compliant class

```
var tmpClass: DoSomethingProtocol?
```

## Inheritance

### Create a base class with the `doSomething` method

```
class DoSomethingBaseClass {
    func doSomething()->Int{ return 0 }
}
```

### Override `doSomething` in your classes

```
class One : DoSomethingBaseClass {
    override func doSomething()->Int{ return 100 }
}

class Two : DoSomethingBaseClass{
    override func doSomething()->Int{ return 200 }
}
```

### Set your `tempClass` variable to be of the super class (polymorphism!)

```
var tmpClass: DoSomethingBaseClass?
```

## General tips

- In Swift `switch`es must be exhaustive (all possible options **must** have a case), to fix this in your example you can simply add

  ```
  default:
      tmpClass = nil
  ```
- Do not forget to unwrap your optional. For safety you can use the `if let` syntax for optional binding:

  ```
  if let tmpUnwrappedClass = tmpClass {
      println(tmpUnwrappedClass.doSomething())
  }
  ```

  You could just use the `!` unwrap operator as in `println(tmpClass!.doSomething())` but this **will fail** when `tmpClass` is nil.
- Your `begin` class has two properties and no initializers. Classes with properties **must** have a designated initializer to set them, that's why I removed the whole class.

Both versions are tested and working in the latest Swift using Playground.

Comment: Set your tempClass variable to be of a protocol compliant class 

"var tmpClass: DoSomethingProtocol?" and initialize "var tmpClass = One()" after that "tmpClass.doSomething()"